# Cross-platform ad-hoc local mobile multiplayer

Tags: android, unity, ios, networking, cross-platform

I want to implement ad-hoc cross-platform (iOS, Android, and PC) device discovery for local multiplayer, like this scenario: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csXYZf2vGdE  Multiple players, each with different devices (iOS, Android, PC). One player starts a game. The others can search and automatically discover his game and enter into a local multiplayer match. This would all be done P2P, without any dedicated game servers.

Is this possible with current technology?

Comment: I edited your question to focus directly on one topic, rather than pondering the different facets of AllJoyn's different technology interactions. If you feel my edit was wrong, feel free to revert or change it, but keep it focused.  I removed the open-ended request for alternatives, because that would be inviting discussion, which is not the SE way.  In my opinion, the best way to find out if AllJoyn will work is to either read the documentation, or try it and see if it works.  You might encounter specific problems with implementation, and then you could post them and get specific answers.

Comment: I researched and found out that AllJoyn doesn't work for iOS in Unity3D.  So you're saying that asking for guidance in implementing cross-platform ad-hoc local mobile multiplayer is against the rules?  It doesn't seem very different from any of the other questions I see in this SE.  My question  is on one top: "cross-platform ad-hoc local mobile multiplayer".

Comment: Here's an example of another similar SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502818/android-ios-peer-to-peer-architecture

Comment: As I said, if you disagree with what I did, feel free to change it. What I did was an attempt to improve your question, with the intent of permitting you to get better answers. If I felt your question was against the rules, I would have voted to close it. You should familiarize yourself with the [help] to get a better idea of what makes for good and bad questions.